# Progressdialog on application startup not working

Tags: android

I want to show a progress dialog "loading" while my app is opening.

I tried AsyncTask and some other methodologies(Uithread, thread) to do this and all of were failed.

I do not know why, but the progressdialog is not showed in my phone screen. I always see a dark screen.

**After getApnData throws exception and my activity UI components are shown, progress dialog works, but it's too late**

Here is some of my code parts.

```
//1-1-1-1-1
//On create or OnStart

LoginProgressTask task1 = new LoginProgressTask();  
        task1.execute();

//Inner class
    class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                getApnData(); // Do your real work here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Boolean.TRUE; // Return your real result here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            LoginUI.this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginUI.this, "", "Loading...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // LoginUI.this.pd.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

---

```
//2-2-2-2-2
//OnCreate or OnStart
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true, false);

thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();


//run
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            firstRunUI();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

//UIRun
    public void firstRunUI() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getApnData();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

//Handler
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            pd.dismiss();


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first of all , 
You can show progress using the following scenario:

1. Use your LoginProgressTask as follows

   new LoginProgressTask().execute();
2. Change

   LoginUI.this.pd =  ProgressDialog.show(LoginUI.this, "", "Loading...", true, true)
3. Use the following on use onCreate or onStart instead of your 2nd block of code in the question

   new LoginProgressTask().execute();

Here are  a complete example

```
class SomeActivity extends Activity {
        ProgressDialog pd ;
        class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
         @Override
        public void onPreExecute(){
         pd = ProgressDialog.show(LoginUI.this, "", "Loading...", true, true);
        }
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        getApnData(); // Do your real work here
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return Boolean.TRUE; // Return your real result here
                }
         }

      @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                pd.dismiss(); //or use handlers it is better

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                     new LoginProgressTask().execute();
    }
    }
```

This will do the job for you!!

**Nad make sure you dismiss the ProgressDialog on PostExecute method***

**NOTE**
Don't Create Views in Main UI thread because that may cause memory leak

**Update**
To update UI Elements from getAbnData() 
You should use Handlers

```
Handler handler = new Hanlder(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(int what){
//changing UI Elements code comes here

}
}
```

from within the code use handler.sendMessage(NUMER)

and then it will handle message

[Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: Not for job, to help some of my friend. He is new on android development. I have tried this methods before and they work fine.

Comment: @tgrll This will do the job for you!! not meaning the job you actually work for , but it is an acronym for doing the work or the job of the code !!! that is , don't misunderstand please , and give us a feedback if the solution works

Comment: Sorry for wrong understanding . 
Yeap it is working and my code is working now.  I have tried this methods in my projects before and they work fine. 
But not in this project. It sounds strange.
His code is little complex. For example in getApnData(), he reaches UI elements and  changing some of them. setText, setEnabled etc.
I fixed some parts of the code and progress dialog is shown now.
But in a little time it's rotating, after that it is locking. 
Still need help.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code you solve your problem, even not using AsyncTask. Hope it helps you.

```
 private void Load() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
        p = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        p.setMessage("Loading...");
        p.setCancelable(false);
        p.show();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }).start();
    } 
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        p.dismiss();
        switch (msg.what) {

        case 0:
            //LOAD YOUR ACTIVITY HERE
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I checked myself, it Works, the error is in the codepart-1. have you tested my code? Does the screen keep blackened?

Comment: Yeah black, but i find the solution. But only part of the solution. This time progress dialog is locked .