# How to update the TextView of an Activity with the current value of a counter running in the background?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a counter that increases by 1 every 1 second displaying 
its current value in a TextView.

Everything works fine until the Activity is destroyed and then recreated.
In those cases, the counter resets to 0.

I have read that I must put the code of the counter inside
a custom **Service**, so it gets executed in the background.
Then, I should comunicate my Activity (which contains the
TextView) with a **BroadcastServicer**.

I have followed a few tutorials about BroadcastReceivers 
but still I don't get how to solve this problem.

Could you please show me the right way to
comunicate the BroadCastReceiver with the Service 
in order to update the TextView inside the Activity?.

This is my code of my Activity so far:

```
public class CounterActivity extends Activity{
    private long startTime = 0;
    private Handler h = new Handler();
    private TextView tvCounter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);
        tvCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCounter);

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
               int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
               int minutes = seconds / 60;
               seconds     = seconds % 60;

               tvCounter.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

               h.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        };

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        h.postDelayed(run, 0);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that what you want to achieve? I mean displaying counter.

Comment: yes, it should run in the background because when the activity gets destroyed the counter resets.

Comment: When do you want it to reset?

Comment: I want to stop the counter on the clickListener of a button that is not implemented yet, but it should be a trivial stop button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your startTime using code below , then counter will not reset~

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putLong("starttime", startTime);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState != null){
     startTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("starttime");
  }else{
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

consider using Async task and handlers to update UI components

- [Async Task documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: You are using very limied API capablilites of handler please refere to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419672/progressdialog-on-application-startup-not-working/16420093#16420093

Comment: For tasks that do not require work on background thread, you don't need to use threads. Handler is enough.